# System binaries fail with "Exec format error", apt-get fails with "117: Structure needs cleaning"

Tags: pi-4, boot, sd-card, raspbian-buster

Most system commands fail with "Exec format error" and `apt-get upgrade` fails with "117: Structure needs cleaning". Does this sound like an SD-card corruption? If not, what could help fix it?

The system is currently still up (without errors) but I am reluctant to restart it.

```bash
pi@black-pearl:~ $ uptime
-bash: /usr/bin/uptime: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
pi@black-pearl:~ $ date
Mon  8 Aug 21:12:42 CEST 2022
pi@black-pearl:~ $ ps aux
-bash: /usr/bin/ps: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
pi@black-pearl:~ $ ls -al /usr/bin/ps
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 83584 May 31  2018 /usr/bin/ps
pi@black-pearl:~ $ file /usr/bin/ps
-bash: /usr/bin/file: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
pi@black-pearl:~ $ sudo -i
root@black-pearl:~# apt-get update
Hit:1 http://packages.azlux.fr/debian buster InRelease                                                                                                   
Get:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster InRelease [15.0 kB]                                                                                
Hit:3 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster InRelease                                                       
Hit:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/raspbian buster InRelease                            
Fetched 15.0 kB in 10s (1,543 B/s)                                                                                                                                   
Reading package lists... Done
root@black-pearl:~# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  python-colorzero
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove it.
E: Archives directory /var/cache/apt/archives/partial is missing. - Acquire (117: Structure needs cleaning)
root@black-pearl:~# uname -a
Linux black-pearl 5.10.17-v7+ #1414 SMP Fri Apr 30 13:18:35 BST 2021 armv7l GNU/Linux
root@black-pearl:~# cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
root@black-pearl:/# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        15G  2.9G   11G  21% /
devtmpfs        430M     0  430M   0% /dev
tmpfs           463M     0  463M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           463M   47M  416M  11% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           463M     0  463M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1  253M   49M  204M  20% /boot
log2ram         512M  1.2M  511M   1% /var/log
log2ram         512M   50M  463M  10% /var/lib/docker/containers
overlay          15G  2.9G   11G  21% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/f5d181092e98c5bbc8a89b85af68884ee01ca71016256fa0f3efd016e2fcb56b/merged
overlay          15G  2.9G   11G  21% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/cf7b2690345318f4b4f0b36393850ac93db22c935539e70ae2c341e100e1d82e/merged
overlay          15G  2.9G   11G  21% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/25b84ff706ec89a2947a644bff3e23cd341fee6782f795589c71ea0a1873ac58/merged
overlay          15G  2.9G   11G  21% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/35adcca15ced4b8d8637f96d7c091a44b9793080857eeba2df68a600410a584b/merged
tmpfs            93M     0   93M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Answer (score 2):

> The system is currently still up

In what looks to be a completedly screwed sense. Trying to salvage this is probably a bad to impossible idea.

I'd guess this is the culprit, a non-standard entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or a file in `/etc/apt/sources.d/`:

```
> apt-get update
Hit:1 http://packages.azlux.fr/debian buster InRelease
```

That's a repo which was included in a recent update, and it replaced a bunch of your system binaries with non-arm versions (eg., x86 or x86-64), which will not work on a Pi.  You could confirm this by examining the binaries, the simplest way is with, eg. `file /usr/bin/ps`, probably by sticking the SD card in another system.
A valid result here would be one of:

```
ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV)
ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV)
```

Depending which OS version you are using.  Anything else, eg:

```
ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV)
```

is no good.

At some point during that update process something necessary to the process itself got replaced, which caused apt to end up out of sorts.  Undoing all that is not as simple as just trying to run a new update; you will likely waste a lot of time and end up with a somewhat different mess.

Salvage your data etc. and start from scratch (or a backup from prior to the event). And in future, make sure you understand what you are doing befor you add source repo urls to apt.

Comment: Thanks for this analysis. You certainly knew what to look out for. So it appears the system pretty much was in that state from the start. The culprit: https://github.com/azlux/log2ram#install

Comment: However, given that log2ram was created specifically for the Pi I'm confused why it could have caused the installation of non-ARM binaries.

Comment: Hmmm -- I did not look yesterday, but there are in fact ARM binaries there (you can load that url into a browser and browse the repo directories).  Also, there is a pretty limited set of packages there that doesn't cover the stuff that was replaced (eg, `ps` is from package `procps`, it is not there).  So it may not be that.   I am fairly *but not absolutely* certain that `exec format error` is only thrown specifically for that error, that the file is a binary executable but the format is wrong...

Comment: ...I can't get it to happen with other things that are set executable permissions wise but not executable in reality (text files, images, blobs, etc).  If it is worthwhile for you to pursue this (without holding out much hope the system can be fixed), I would start by putting that card in another machine (or in the Pi, but running a clean install, if you have a USB -> microSD dongle) and see what `file` says about those binaries.